# How can i get selector including class name

Tags: css, selector

[image]

In html inspection window, i usually use 'copy Selector'
but that just brings `<tag>`s , sometimes including `.classname`.

I want to use 'copy Selector' that includes all classnames in tags.

How can i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just click on **New Style Rule** button (plus sign on top right corner of Elements tab) in inspector, it will generate a style rule containing class or id and tag in some cases. Then you can copy its generated value.

[image]

Comment: It's really awesome Thx a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Firefox developer tool
Choose your element -> right click Choose Copy -> CSS Path

Result after copying: `html body#gsr.hp.vasq.big div#viewport.ctr-p div#main.content span#body.ctr-p center div#lga img#hplogo`

---

[image]

Comment: before: Okay i will install Firefox and do this
after: wow it's crazy i love firefox that's awesome!!